# Метод equals и ==

Tags: java

Фрагмент кода

```
for(int i =0; i<mas.length; i++){
  if(mas[i]=="-"){             //проверка является ли символ mas[i]равен -
    int[] m =new int[2];
    m[0]=Integer.valueOf(mas[i+2]);

    m[1]=Integer.valueOf(mas[i+3]);
  }
}
```

В данном случае в проверке равенства не возвращается `true`, если вместо `==` применить метод `equals` - то все в порядке.

Попробовал применить отдельно вариант сравнения используя  `==`

```
String s ="-";
system.out.println(s=="-");
```

возвратило `true`, в чем разница от первого примера, почему там не возвращает `true`?

Comment: Посмотрев на вопросы, посоветую @JAVAvladuxa перестать изучать язык программирования по примерам в этих интернетах и засесть за книги. А не то в один прекрасный день может сложиться ощущение уверенного знания языка, и при этом будут пробелы в фундаментальных вещах.

Comment: А, кстати, Вам религия не позволяет сравнивать mas[i] с символом '=' ?

Comment: @alexlz: исходя из вопроса, ТС не понимает, в чём разница.

Comment: И кстати да, то, что в Java на строках `==` работает неинтуитивным образом — пример неуместного догматизма.

Comment: Это на первых порах оно работает "неинтуитивно". А потом, когда приходит понимание, что String - это всего навсего объекты, все стает на свои места. Но есть есть интернированные строки... а там равно работает.

Comment: @KoVadim: Я понимаю, что внутри это объекты. Но тем не менее, с точки зрения здравого смысла, у строк [семантика значения](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_object): никто ведь не скажет, что "Федя" и "Федя" — это две _разных_ строки. У строки, как у value-type, не должно быть собственной сущности помимо значения, точно так же, как у константы `5`. То, что строка есть объект — внутренняя деталь имплементации, которую программист почему-то должен держать в голове.

Comment: для этого нужно было делать встроенный тип. Тогда все было именно так. Вас ведь не смущает, когда два объекта имеют одинаковое значение полей, у них переопределен метод toString, который выводит одно и тоже, но при этом `==` работает "неинтуитивно":)

Comment: А на мой взгляд, тут как раз все интуитивно. Прямая аналогия с указателями (*конечно на дескриптор объекта*) и `strcmp()` в Си.

Comment: @KoVadim: Нужно было, конечно. По поводу объектов — зависит от их семантики. Есть случаи, когда равенство определяется лишь значениями полей (value type). Например, дата или возраст. Есть случаи, когда объект имеет самостоятельную сущность (entity type). Например, если двух человек зовут одинаково, и у них одинаковый возраст, это всё ещё не один и тот же человек.

Comment: @KoVadim: В C#, например, разрешено переопределять `operator ==`, в результате равенство для value type _можно_ сделать интуитивным. Java для простоты языка не разрешает перегрузку операторов, поэтому первым делом приходится учить, что для value type оператор `==` никуда не годится.

Comment: @avp: Дело в том, что языки разные. C как раз и построен на том, что указатель есть по большому счёту лишь число, и равенство есть равенство чисел. В C нету высокоуровневой объектной семантики. Java же — язык высокого уровня, она по своей идеологии пытается прятать тот факт, что все объекты на нижнем уровне абстракции всего лишь наборы чисел. Поэтому выбор для строки не-value-семантики кажется мне очень спорным.

Comment: @VladD, языки, конечно, немного разные. Но, я не сказал бы, что уровни Java и С++ сильно отличаются. (Особенно после того, как Unicode за размер char в Java вылезли).

Просто Java своей JVM от реального железа отодвинута.

Comment: @avp: в C++, в отличие от Java, есть перегруженный `std::string::operator ==`, ведущий себя ожидаемым образом :-P

Comment: @VlaD
а в Java перегрузили операцию new String("text"), заменив на "text". Разве в С++ сравнивают два объекта через == ? Или надо тоже что-то переопределить? В этом плане все предельно ясно и понятно - стринг объект, сравнивается перегруженным методом. И не надо разводить холиваров)

Comment: @Антон Феоктистов:

1. Этого недостаточно, и пример из вопроса есть тому подтверждение.
2. Да, в C++ сравнивают объекты через `==`, а что? Разница в том, что разработчик класса в C++ может переопределить этот оператор. Предельно ясно и просто — если у вас всегда ровно один, всегда правильный оператор сравнения.
3. И не надо участвовать в холиварах ;-)

Answer (score 13):

Любопытный факт. Для экономии памяти в Java используется пул литералов. Все строки, созданные так:

```
String s = "abc";
```

помещаются в пул. Сравнивать две строки, лежащие в пуле можно оператором `==`

```
String s1 = "abc";
String s2 = "abc";
s1 == s2; // true
```

Так как эти строки созданы литералами, они ссылаются на одно место в пуле, поэтому они равны. А вот строки, созданные оператором `new` или конкатенацией строк (пусть даже литералов) в пул не кладутся. Они кладутся в объекты, хранящиеся в куче (heap). Поэтому сравнивать их оператором `==` нецелесообразно, здесь нужен метод `equals`:

```
String s1 = "abc";
String s2 = "ab" + "c";
String s3 = new String("abc");
String s4 = s3;
s1 == s2; // false
s1 == s3; // false
s3 == s4; // true
s1.equals(s2); // true
```

Comment: @fori1ton, только никогда нельзя быть до конца уверенным, что ссылки на 2 одинаковые **`"abc"`** будут равны.

В пределах одного .java файла - почти наверняка. В разных .jar  - не обязательно.

Comment: вы утверждаете на основе какого-то источника? мне лично кажется что true возвращается потому что компилятор выделяет константу и подставляет ее во всех 3х случаях. поэтому получается что ссылка на обьект у всех одна

Comment: @jmu: я не могу указать источник, но исходя из общих соображений: интернирование выполняется на этапе компиляции и только для констант времени компиляции. А если строка _вычисляется_ (как в примере у ТС), то компилятор по идее создаст новую строку, не будет же он в рантайме искать по списку интернированных строк?

Comment: @jmu: [источник](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern%28%29):

> All literal strings and string-valued constant expressions are interned.

Хотя это совпадает с тем, что вы пишете в ответе.

Comment: [Этот ответ на SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15809584/276994) утверждает, что в разных jar интернированные строки будут не совпадать:

> ...and only when they're compiled at the same time. If you have two Java strings sufficiently separated in time and space (e.g., compiled into separate JAR files), they will not be the same object

Answer (score 5):

`==` сравнивает ссылки на строки которые у каждой строки уникальны и неизменяемые
`equals` - сравнивает содержимое этих строк (в контексте строк `String` будет приведено к типу `String`) или `Object`, данный метод принимает аргумент `Object`, может быть переопределен с приведением разных типов, если это понадобится в других контекстах.

Comment: То есть mas[i] это ссылка на значение элемента?

Comment: @lexx9427, насколько помню, если `String mas;`, то *совсем не так*.

mas[i]  безусловно имеет тип **char**.

А вот дальше уже интересней, поскольку String это особый класс (или его правильней называть встроенный тип?) в Java. 

В `if (mas[i] == "-")` компилятор неявно преобразует `mas[i]` типа `char` к объекту типа `Character` у которого есть метод `toString`.

Результатом вызова этого метода будет объект типа String. Далее в операторе `==` будут сравниваться ссылки (реально адреса) этого объекта и `String` константы `"-"`!!!

Понятно, что они (эти ссылки (адреса)) будут разными. Вот и все.

Comment: Забавно выглядит комментарий, вызванный комментарием, который после этого "ответа" *удаляют*.

Answer (score 2):

== это примитивный оператор, сравнивая объекты старайтесь использовать equals, для некоторых стандартных классов оператор == и метод equals работают идентично, но не для всех.

// + немного офотопа:
и ещё обязательно переопределяйте метод equals если он вам нужен для сравнения собственных классов. Процесс переопределения метода очень хорошо описан у Хортсмана.