# Где ошибка? Почему while не реагирует на переменную?

Tags: java

Есть такой код:
(Пишу для игры одной)

```
package jerke;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

public class HttpURLConnectionExample {

private final static String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    HttpURLConnectionExample http = new HttpURLConnectionExample();
    init();
    mainLoop();
}

private static void mainLoop() throws Exception {
    String[] chat = null;
    String message = null;
    sendMsg("");
    while (message != "!stopit"){
        String cht = getChat();
        cht = cht.replaceAll("<###>", "\n");
        chat = cht.trim().split("\n");
        String chto = chat[0];
        String[] data = chto.substring(10).split("<>"); // 50ml
        String logi = data[0].toString();      
        System.out.println(data[1]);

        message = data[1];

        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
    };
    sendMsg("Elite hax0r bot went offline.");   
}

static void init() throws Exception {

    String cht = getChat();
    cht = cht.replaceAll("<###>", "\n");
    String[] chat = cht.trim().split("\n");
    System.out.println(chat);
}

//------------------------------------
//Далее скорее всего не нужная вам часть
//------------------------------------


// HTTP GET request
private static String getChat() throws Exception {

    String url = "https://www.hackingsimulator.com/i133/process_chat.php?cmd=get_chat&u=hax0r&p=1q2w3e4r&channel=home";

    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    // optional default is GET
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");

    //add request header
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();
    System.out.println(response.toString());
    //print result
    return response.toString().replace('*', ' ').replace(')', ' ');

}

// HTTP POST request
private static void sendMsg(String msg) throws Exception {

    String url = "https://www.hackingsimulator.com/i133/process_chat.php";
    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    //add reuqest header
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");

    String urlParameters = "cmd=add_chat&u=hax0r&p=1q2w3e4r&channel=home&msg=" + msg;

    // Send post request
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
    System.out.println("Post parameters : " + urlParameters);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();

    //print result
    System.out.println(response.toString());

}

}
```

Знаю, код - лапша, но почему всё-таки не реагирует while на переменную message?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Метод equals и ==](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/224250/%d0%9c%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4-equals-%d0%b8)

Comment: Если кто-нибудь своим ответом-таки решил вашу проблему, то не поленитесь отметить ответ "галочкой" (рядом со "стрелочками" у ответов), чтобы он не висел в списке неотвеченных :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Сравнивайте строку через:

```
while (!"!stopit".equals(message) {
```

Т.е. проблема в том, что вы сравниваете ссылки на экземпляры класса `String`, а не их значения.

Подробную информацию касательно того, как работает `operator ==` и `equals` (в частности для строк) можно найти [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/496081/200756).

Comment: NullPointerException :)

Comment: @WarSpaker, а чего ж вы хотели, если двумя строками выше сами указали message = null ? задайте любое не-null значение

Comment: Упс, забыл. Ну теперь заработало :)

Comment: @WarSpaker обычно лучше писать `"text".equals(variable)`.

Comment: @WarSpaker ну я там подправил вариант с учетом вашего `null`'а, надеюсь, я правильно понял как вы хотели обрабатывать такую ситуацию?

Answer (score 7):

Вероятно, потому что строки надо сравнивать через `equals`. Должно заработать, если указать `while (!message.equals("!stopit"))`. В противном случае вы сравниваете две ячейки памяти - а они, конечно, не равны.